# SQL Replace in select with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, replace, left-join

I have the following query that works fine:

```
SELECT 'User ID' AS 'uid',
       'E-Mail' AS 'email',
       'Reason' AS 'reason'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.subid AS 'uid',
       a.email AS 'email',
       b.data AS 'reason'
FROM sms7l_subscriber a
LEFT JOIN sms7l_history b ON a.subid = b.subid
WHERE (a.confirmed = 0
       OR a.enabled = 0
       OR a.accept = 0)
  AND b.action = unsubscribed
```

Now I want to do some string replacements on b.data directly... it contains a rather ugly to read string e.g. - '`REASON::UNSUB_SURVEY_FREQUENT REASON::UNSUB_SURVEY_IRRELEVANT REASON::Some text from textfield`'

I want to replace '`REASON::`' with '`Reason:` ' and as well replace '`UNSUB_SURVEY_FREQUENT`' with the according string etc. I need to make around 4-5 string replacements all on 'b.data'

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 'User ID' AS 'uid',
       'E-Mail' AS 'email',
       'Reason' AS 'reason'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.subid AS 'uid' , a.email AS 'email',
REPLACE (b.data,
         'REASON::',
         'Reason: ') AS 'reason'
FROM sms7l_subscriber a
LEFT JOIN sms7l_history b ON a.subid = b.subid
WHERE (a.confirmed = 0
       OR a.enabled = 0
       OR a.accept = 0)
  AND b.action = unsubscribed
```

But it doesn't work. Unfortunally I have to do this in a single query and it has to contain the replacements. Any hints on how to properly wrap the replace command would be great.

Update: Thank you for the input so far. Here is some additional information I missed to mention that might have caused some confusion:
It's a MySQL Database and I don't want to actually replace the strings in the database itself or create a new table - I only want to replace the strings in the query result. The reason behind this: there is a very convinient tool for the cms I use that allows me to render the result of a mysql query into a nicely formated html table (it's sortable, searchable etc.).
Unfortunally I can only use a single query and I cannot call any further procedures to format the query result. The first line of the result can be set as title and hence the 'union all' statement in the beginning of my query. Since I want that the table is easy to read I want to replace (translate) the strings on 'b.data'. E.g. instead of 'REASON::UNSUB_SURVEY_IRRELEVANT' I want to have 'Reason: The content of the newsletter doesn't intrest me anymore'... 'REASON::UNSUB_SURVEY_FREQUENT' should get translated accordingly...

I was hoping that even if the SQL query gets rather convoluted in the end it would save me to write a proper module for my cms.

The error message:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near... (and than comes the query string).
```

(Thank for the format changes on the SQL query - much better to read now).

Comment: what does doesn't work mean?

Comment: what RDBS?  Microsoft SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle....?

Comment: You said _"I need to make around 4-5 string replacements all on 'b.data'"_, but there's only one REPLACE statement that was shown here. Can you show the message error ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an `UPDATE` query to change your data and you don't need the `UNION` on the column titles for this update

```
    UPDATE sms7l_subscriber a 
    LEFT JOIN sms7l_history b ON a.subid = b.subid 
    SET b.data = REPLACE (b.data,  'REASON::','Reason: ')
    WHERE (a.confirmed = 0 or a.enabled = 0 or a.accept = 0) and b.action = unsubscribed
```

This is standard ANSI since you did not specified the RDBMS

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: I don't need the data in the tables - it's more that I have a very convinient tool that renders the result of a single sql query into a nice sortable table for the cms I use. That's why I add the titles in the first column with the 'union' all and why I want to replace the some strings.